# Different output format for cin/ofstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream, c++98

### INTRODUCTION AND RELEVANT INFORMATION:

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class Example
{
    int m_a;
    int m_b;
    public:
    // usual stuff, omitted for brevity
    friend ostream & operator<< (ostream & os, const Example &e)
    {
        return os << m_a << m_b;
    }
};
```

### QUESTION:

I want to keep default behavior for `cin`, but the following format when writing to `ofstream`:

```
m_a , m_b
```

### MY EFFORTS TO SOLVE THIS:

I have tried searching here, but haven't found any similar question.

I have tried searching online, but still haven't found anything helpful.

I have tried to add

```
friend ofstream & operator<< (ofstream & ofs, const Example &e)
{ 
    return ofs << m_a << ',' << m_b;
}
```

into the class, but that produced a compiler error. To be honest, this approach feels wrong, but i had to try it before coming here for help.

Comment: "_but that produced a compiler error._" What is the error?

Comment: I've tried to replicate the code adding the specific friend function, and it compiles.

Comment: @FirstStep: I apologize for replying now, I have just returned from work. The error message is this: `error C2440: 'return' : cannot convert from 'std::basic_ostream<char,std::char_traits<char>>' to 'std::ofstream &'` but I do not know what that means. I am Googling as i type this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When chaining operators, all the standard `<<` will return an `ostream&` reference.

Then your `return ...` will not work, because the value doesn't match the `ofstream&` return type.

Just use `ostream&` in your user defined `operator<<`, and it should work.

Comment: I have changed `friend ofstream & operator<< (ofstream & ofs, const Example &e)` into `friend ostream & operator<< (ofstream & ofs, const Example &e)` as you have said, and it worked. I have upvoted and officially accepted. Thank you so much! Regards.

Answer (score 0):

A string's syntax is `"S"` even if it is **one character** string. And `fstream` takes a string and not a char. Therefore, this should work:

```
friend ofstream & operator<< (ofstream & ofs, const Example &e) 
{ 
    ofs << e.m_a << "," << e.m_b; // " instead of '
    return ofs;
}
```

Comment: I have tried it, but still failed. The point was to change the return type from `ofstream` to `ostream` as user *Bo Perrson* suggested. Then everything works. Thank you for trying to help, I appreciate it.

Comment: It is okay. Glad we were able to help :)

Answer (score 0):

I initially thought you just have forgotten the object e in your implementation.

```
friend ostream & operator<< (ofstream & ofs, const Example &e)
{ 
   return ((ostream&) ofs) << e.m_a << ',' << e.m_b;
}
```

with the following explanation friend binary operator with 2 arguments inside a class are intrinsically external methods declared in the class body.

But after compiling with clang++, ofstream << int complains with the error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ofstream' (aka 'basic_ofstream') and 'int') and you should also add the cast to ostream.

In fact ofstream << int don't know if it should use ofstream << Equation or ostream << int and the ambiguity causes a compilation error.

So you should be aware of the overloading that is likely to generate future compilation errors.